# Push a variable in a vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How to push a variable in a vector in Matlab?

Something like this:

```
A = [5 2 3];
push(A, 7);
% A = [5 2 3 7]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found the answer.

Use this:

```
A = [A, 7];
```

Or this:

```
A(end + 1) = 7;
```

Comment: `A=[A,4];` Is the most commonly used solution because it easily generalizes to more complex situations. However the first solution will also work if your vector is transposed so both have their strongpoints.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: can you give an example where the first method will fail?

Comment: @naught101 As disadvantage of the first I only mentioned the second generalizes more easily. Suppose you want to append `A` to the right of `A` you can simply do: `A=[A,A]` whilst for the first method you would need to do: `A(:,end+1:end+size(A,2)) = A`

Comment: @naught101 The first will fail when the vector is a vector of structures, and it begins empty; e.g. `my_struct.a = 10; all_structs = []; all_structs(end+1) = my_struct;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stack it vertically you can use

```
A = [A; 7]
```

but for this to be executed, A should of same dimentions as next argument.
for example if

```
A=[1,2
   3,4]
```

you can stack a vector of length 2 in A as

```
A = [A;5,6]
```