# How to detect 4 digit using regexp

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How do I get the year (4 digits) when given a source code, I can only detect the day (29), but could not detect the year(1997). There is something wrong in my regexp checking.

```
age = regexp(CharData,'(\d{1,4})','match','once')
```

For example,

> Registered On
>       March 29, 1997

**Desired output:** *1997*

**Error output:** *29*

```
for i = 1:2

   data2=fopen(strcat('DATA\PRE-PROCESS_DATA\F22_TR\f22_TR_pdata_',int2str(i),''),'r')
   CharData = fread(data2, '*char');  %read text file and store data in CharData
   fclose(data2);

   age = regexp(CharData,'(\d{4})','match','once')

end
```

> file : f22_TR_pdata_1 --> Registered On
>       June 24, 1997
>
> file : f22_TR_pdata_2 --> Registered On
>       March 29, 1997

**Age:** *1997*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To only grab four digits

```
age = regexp(CharData,'(\d{4})','match','once')
```

Doing `d{1,4}`  means look for numbers with a length between 1 and 4.   Meaning, `1`, `29`, `123`, `4444` would all match because their length is between 1 and 4

`d{4}`  says, get me the number with exact length of 4.  Meaning, `1997`, `2001`, `1800` would all match.

Comment: yes, i understand~ if i got more than 1 file, then how would i going to store all the 'age' in array form?

Comment: You should ask a new question because it is unrelated. If the answer helped reslove the issue then accept it, please. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756497/push-a-variable-in-a-vector-in-matlab for a vector and for arrays tutorial read http://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/matlab_arrays.htm