# dynamically fill vector without assigning empty matrix

Tags: matlab

Oftentimes I need to dynamically fill a vector in Matlab. However this is sligtly annoying since you first have to define an empty variable first, e.g.:

```
[a,b,c]=deal([]);
for ind=1:10
  if rand>.5 %some random condition to emphasize the dynamical fill of vector
    a=[a, randi(5)];
  end
end
a %display result
```

Is there a better way to implement this 'push' function, so that you do not have to define an empty vector beforehand? People tell me this is nonsensical in Matlab- if you think this is the case please explain why.

related: [Push a variable in a vector in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756497/push-a-variable-in-a-vector-in-matlab), [is-there-an-elegant-way-to-create-dynamic-array-in-matlab](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/21004-is-there-an-elegant-way-to-create-dynamic-array-in-matlab)

Comment: Instead of constructing an empty matrix, it is more efficient (i.e. faster) to preallocate a matrix of the correct size whenever possible.

Comment: @m7913d I think that's impossible in this case, because of the randomicity. But I don't understand the "annoying" thing in the question. Matlab is so comfortable in the manner of declarations and pre-allocations, you need some C coding before complaining about annoying defenitions...

Comment: by randomicity you mean the non-predictable way you add to the vector `a`?

Comment: Two [working examples](http://rextester.com/WWUYA34703) in Octave. I do not know if MATLAB accept that .

Comment: @rahnema1 No, it doesn't work in MATLAB.

Comment: Despite the random size of the final `a` in this case, you know it'll be no larger than `10`. You could do `a = nan(10,1);`, then `a(ind) = randi(5)` within the loop (not constantly pushing to `a`) and finally `a = a(~isnan(a));` to remove the original `NaN` values. Potentially friendlier on memory (assuming the array isn't huge)

Comment: @Wolfie That is indeed the same trick as suggested [here](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/21004-is-there-an-elegant-way-to-create-dynamic-array-in-matlab)

Comment: @m7913d Ah I was just freeballing it, glad nice to be backed up on Central!

Comment: What about [this](http://rextester.com/VVK24349)?

Comment: @rahnema1 Checking for existing is indeed a possibility, but will result in more (ennoying) code.The goal of the OP was to limit it as much as possible.

Comment: @rahnema1 Double quotes `"` aren't standard MATLAB syntax (use single `'`), and it would be better to use `exist('h', 'var')` for speed. Overall though this is *more* code and for no performance gain, so not really worth it - although the thought did cross my mind too. Also as an aside, you'd be better of using a matrix `[]` than a cell `{}` for numerical data.

Comment: @Wolfie As in previous comment I noted that it is a possible Octave solution that does not require defining a variable before loop.

Comment: @Wolfie When size of an array is dynamically increased cell usually works better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB, pre-allocation is the way to go. From the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html):

> `for` and `while` loops that incrementally increase the size of a data structure each time through the loop can adversely affect performance and memory use.

As pointed out in the comments by m7913d, there is a question on MathWorks' answers section which addresses this same point, [read it here](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/21004-is-there-an-elegant-way-to-create-dynamic-array-in-matlab).

I would suggest "over-allocating" memory, then reducing the size of the array after your loop.

```
numloops = 10;
a = nan(numloops, 1);
for ind = 1:numloops
    if rand > 0.5
        a(ind) = 1; % assign some value to the current loop index
    end
end
a = a(~isnan(a)); % Get rid of values which weren't used (and remain NaN)
```

---

No, this doesn't decrease the amount you have to write before your loop, it's even worse than having to write `a = []`! However, you're better off spending a few extra keystrokes and minutes writing well structured code than making that saving and having worse code.

Answer (score 1):

It is (as for as I known) not possible in MATLAB to omit the initialisation of your variable before using it in the right hand side of an expression. Moreover it is not desirable to omit it as *preallocating* an array is almost always the right way to go.

As mentioned in [this post](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/21004-is-there-an-elegant-way-to-create-dynamic-array-in-matlab), it is even desirable to preallocate a matrix even if the exact number of elements is not known. To demonstrate it, a small benchmark is desirable:

```
Ns = [1 10 100 1000 10000 100000];
timeEmpty = zeros(size(Ns));
timePreallocate = zeros(size(Ns));

for i=1:length(Ns)
  N = Ns(i);
  timeEmpty(i) = timeit(@() testEmpty(N));
  timePreallocate(i) = timeit(@() testPreallocate(N));
end

figure
semilogx(Ns, timeEmpty ./ timePreallocate);
xlabel('N')
ylabel('time_{empty}/time_{preallocate}');

% do not preallocate memory
function a = testEmpty (N)
  a = [];
  for ind=1:N
    if rand>.5 %some random condition to emphasize the dynamical fill of vector
      a=[a, randi(5)];
    end
  end
end

% preallocate memory with the largest possible return size
function a = testPreallocate (N)
  last = 0;
  a = zeros(N, 1);
  for ind=1:N
    if rand>.5 %some random condition to emphasize the dynamical fill of vector
      last = last + 1;
      a(last) = randi(5);
    end
  end
  a = a(1:last);
end
```

[image]

This figure shows how much time the method without preallocating is slower than preallocating a matrix based on the largest possible return size. Note that preallocating is especially important for large matrices due the the exponential behaviour.